# Associations and tables - appointment with patient and doctor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby Rails. I am trying to link doctor's appointment with users(doctor and patient). There is one user model and it has roles patient and doctor. What is the best way to link this? The appointment should have just one doctor and one user assigned to one appointment slot. Thanks for your help

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :dob, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :doctor, :pps_no, :specialisation_id, :roles, :roles_id, :roles_name, :appointments, :appointments_id
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :appointments, :through => :users_appointments
  has_many :users_appointments
   has_and_belongs_to_many :specialisations
  has_many :roles, :through => :roles_users
  has_many :roles_users
  has_secure_password
  GENDERS = [ "Female", "Male" ]
#Roles = %w[admin, doctor, patient]
  def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby on Rails guides on associations actually have a very nice illustration of what you are looking for: physician, appointments and patients:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-through-association

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would require 2 models:doctor and patient, I have one model: users and would like to assign doctor and patient to the appointment.

Comment: @user2333742 post your code in your question instead of trying to edit PNY's answer